# Is there a way to install both tabular and multidimensional modes?

Tags: ssas

I have started studying for the MCSE BI exam. I would like to have both the multidimensional and tabular modes available for studying/practice purposes. I have a SQL Server 2014 Developer Edition with tabular mode installed.

Is it simply a matter of installing another named instance? Seems like there's a gotcha somewhere in there, but I have not found it in the research I have done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your own question. You simply install another instance of SSAS.

Comment: It seemed so obvious. I kept talking myself into it being more than that.