# How to have MS Analysis server setup of both modes: multi dimension and tabular

Tags: sql-server, ssas

Ref: [Is there a way to install both tabular and multidimensional modes?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101729/is-there-a-way-to-install-both-tabular-and-multidimensional-modes)

The answer was .."You answered your own question. You simply install another instance of SSAS."..

My MS SQL 2014 has a database engine installed with AdventureWorks DB and AdventureWorksDW DB. I also have installed Analysis server with a database containing a multi-dim cube.

I tried to install a another instance of SSAS to allow me to test the tabular mode, but the DVD disk did not give me the option to add another instance of SSAS for tabular.

What am I missing?

How do I do this .."You simply install another instance of SSAS.".. for the new instance of SSAS to source data off my already installed AdventureWorkdsDW dataBase.

Thanks - First response was the answer

Answer (score 2):

When you begin installation wizard via **new stand-alone Installation** option, you might have missed to select **Perform a new installation ..** option at Installation type which is first thing to select in the wizard.

[image]

After this you would proceed with **Product key** -> **License terms** -> [Feature selection as Tabular](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/install-windows/install-analysis-services)

Or following command straight-away install new SSAS Instance with Tabular mode, command has to be run from the same directory of installation media or relace `Setup.exe` with media path.

```
Setup.exe /q /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms /ACTION=install /FEATURES=AS /ASSERVERMODE=TABULAR /INSTANCENAME=SSAS_Tab /INDICATEPROGRESS /ASSVCACCOUNT=.\administrator /ASSVCPASSWORD=<administratorpw> /ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS=.\administrator
```